# How to set up blob storage Property before web activity drop a file into Blob storage?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created pipeline in Azure Data factory in which I'm Have web activity which copy the excel(xlsx) file from Dropbox App console and have another web activity which copy the file into Blob Storage, Pipeline is executing successfully, it is copying the file in same xlsx format in blob Storage as well but when I open the excel file from blob storage getting error that "The file myfilename.xlsx may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension"

when the web activity copy the file I see it has content-Type = Applicatoin/octent-stream, I did try to change the content-type = application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, Any help would be appreciate to set the blob storage property before I copy my excel file from web activity output.

Answer (score 0):

The web activity's associated service and dataset characteristics are to be applied. I'll give you a solution that I know will work in the interim. Use two online activities. The data is initially retrieved from the blob. The first web activity's output is used as the body of the second web activity. In the example below, I substitute another blob for the website. (It essentially duplicates the blob.)

Here, the URL looks like this to obtain the blob:

https://.blob.core.windows.net///;

As well, I employ MSI authentication. You must assign the Data Factory rights in the storage account (or container) access control for this to function.

[image]

[image]

The header x-ms-version must then be added, along with the value 2017-11-09. (A picture of an earlier solution illustrates this.)

You should use https://storage.azure.com as the resource.

If an error message appears,

[image]

AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

This operation cannot be carried out under the terms of this request.Then you might need to visit your storage account and grant additional permissions, as seen below. Wait for the permissions to spread over a few minutes; otherwise, you risk getting a false negative.

[image]

Comment: I have added above activities as you have explained and my pipeline executed successfully as well but still when I open the file I am getting same error which I got earlier.   "The file myfilename.xlsx may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension"

Comment: Might be the Excel file is corrupted or The Excel file is not compatible with the version of MS Excel you’re using. @Priyom